# Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm Clarification

Tags: probability-distributions, simulation

All-

Could you please clarify:

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm), step two states at the end if the candidate is rejected, set xt+1 = xt, instead. I don't quite understand this, so you will have two of the exact same point? If your acceptance probability is low, won't you have multiple of the same point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a repetition of the previous point.

Comment: How is that a good estimation of the density? You never get the exact same point using other methods

Comment: @Henk It depends which "other methods" you're talking about. (E.g. Gibbs sampling with a finitely supported discrete distribution will give you repeated points, too.) The idea is that high density points are repeated in order to more accurately approximate the density. If you want a more in-depth explanation, read the relevant proofs, I suppose.

Comment: @Henk Or just read the "intuition" section of the Wikipedia article, which seems to provide an adequate explanation.